# Trying to host static site through visual code, but getting error after build

Tags: c#, iis

So I am learning C# and I am trying to deploy a simple static website and I am getting the following error message:

> HTTP Error 404.0 - Not Found The resource you are looking for has been
>   removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable. Most
>   likely causes: The directory or file specified does not exist on the
>   Web server. The URL contains a typographical error. A custom filter or
>   module, such as URLScan, restricts access to the file.

Does anyone know what it could potentially be?

I went back and looked at the possible causes and everything is fine, atleast I think.

This is how I added the website.

[image]

I mapped the domain name,  webapi.localhost.net, with the local server like this. I then put the modified file back as an administrator in C:\Windows\system32\drivers\etc 
[image]

This is how i have my IISsetup. 
  [image]

**> > Detailed Error Information:**
Module    IIS Web Core
Notification   MapRequestHandler
Handler    StaticFile  Error Code    0x80070002
Requested URL    http://webapi.localhost.net:80/api/user
Physical Path   C:\Users\User Name\source\repos\webapi\api\user
Logon Method   Anonymous 
Logon User    Anonymous

> More Information: This error means that the file or directory does
>   not  exist on the server. Create the file or directory and try the
>   request  again.

Comment: When are you getting this error? Your title implies after build. Does that mean during the deployment process? Or do you believe you've deployed, but then when you try to hit the site through the browser that you get a 404?

Comment: @csb00 Could you provide full URL that gives you 404 error?

Comment: You have logging enabled.  Did you check the logs?  From cmd.exe try  > Ping localhost.  You can also check cmd.exe >Netstat -a which should indicate host is listening on port 80 (from views above).  Are you trying to connect local or remote?  If you are remote checking PING using IP address instead of localhost.

Comment: @mason. I believe I deployed. This error is happening when I hit the site through the browser.

Comment: @yW0K5o I just updated the post with that information

Comment: You might want to make sure the app pool's identity user has permission to access this directory. Since it's in what appears to be your personal directory, a system account may not have read permissions to get it. Alternatively, try moving the source out into a publicly accessible directory like `C:\Source...`

Comment: Did you make sure managed code is enabled for your application pool? Is this .NET Framework or .NET Core?

Comment: @jdweng I am trying to connect locally. I just used Netstat  and the webapi host does not appear.

Comment: @mason this is .Net Framework

Comment: This question probably belongs on https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Then server is not running.   You cannot connect until the server is listening on port 80.  Is the service running?  Is it set to manual or automatic startup when computer is started?  There is a check box in picture above saying "Start Website Immediately". Is it checked?

Comment: @csb00 Do you have file `user`? Static file in IIS usually means a file with .html extension.

Comment: What is your project output? Can you share the contents of the website?

Comment: @jdweng Why would you say the server is not running? If you get a 404 back - that's a response from a server.

Comment: You state this is a static site - but hitting an API endpoint isn't what a static site is.

Comment: Because the service must be listening for it to work.  404 says not found. 404 is a combination of errors.  First that the ACK from TCP was received.  If the service is not running you will not get an ack.

Answer (score 0):

Hi did you notice that Staticfilehandler is handling the request instead of extensionless handler?

So please ensure your asp.net feature has been installed correctly. Then you should see several extensionless handlers displayed in IIS handler mapping. So that extensionlessUrlhandler would process the route instead of accessing the physical path.

Besides, please ensure you have published the project correctly and IIS is using integrated mode.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-forms/overview/deployment/visual-studio-web-deployment/deploying-to-iis

Finally, remember to promise your IUSER and application pool identity have enough permission to access the root folder. I think host website in desktop is not a good idea.

Answer (score -1):

I ended up transferring my project to the desktop and it worked.